# How to make the expected value curve using loess when the x-axis is age as discrete

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, loess

I have a data frame where I need to make the expected value curve using e.g loess. My x-axis is age which is discrete (50, 55.5, 60, 60.5, ..., 70, 70.5). The geom_smooth() using loess does not work. it complains:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

Is there any solution to make the expected value curve considering that I have age in the x-axis as what I explained?

Comment: You should make the age continuous. What do you mean when you say it is discrete?

Comment: If you mean there are fixed categories of age, then a smoothing curve between them makes no sense. If you want to see how a variable changes smoothly according to age, you need to make the ages continuous.

Comment: @AllanCameron it was already continues i change it to age+0.5 for a specific purpose, but now cannot be make it in this range?

Comment: @ Allan Cameron do I have to make it back to continuous? for example 50.5 to what?

Comment: It sounds like you have changed it to a character or factor variable. Try turning it back to a number. `df$Age <- as.numeric(as.character(df$Age))` should do it (where obviously `df$Age` is your age column in its data frame - you didn't tell us what your actual variables were called.